# JSON Parsing using jQuery - Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I am stuck with a problem while parsing the response data in json format.

JSON Output from an external URL:

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "qtext": "Do you like this product?",
    "op": [
        {
            "oid": "1",
            "option": "option1"
        },
        {
            "oid": "2",
            "option": "option2"
        },
        {
            "oid": "3",
            "option": "option3"
        },
        {
            "oid": "4",
            "option": "option4"
        }
    ]
  },
    {
    "id": "16",
    "qtext": "How is the quality of this video?",
    "op": []
    }
]
```

To parse this json, I have written this jQuery code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'jsonexp1.php',
        data: {id:1},
        success: function(data) {
            var pj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(pj,function(k,element){
            $("#content").html($("#content").html()+"<p>"+element.id+" "+element.qtext);
        });
    }
});
```

I am able to read the first two items "id" and "qtext" from the json output. But, I am unable to traverse the other elements.

A guideline will help. Thanks

Comment: what element you want ?

Comment: you need one more `$.each()` in your current `$.each()`.

Comment: I wish to read option & oid both. I am trying with one more $.each()

Comment: Look at Rory McCrossan answer

Answer (score 1):

`op` in the response is an array, so you need another `$.each` loop.

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(k, element) {
        $.each(data.op, function() {
            // do something with the data in the item...
            console.log(this.oid);
            console.log(this.option);
        });
        $("#content").append($('<p />', { text: element.id + " " + element.qtext });
    });
}
```

Also, note you can use `append()` to add an element.

Comment: Thanks Rory! I am trying this out. Appreciating your instant help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this:

```
var htm = '';
$.each(pj,function(k,element){
    htm = $("#content").html() + "<p>" + element.id + " " + element.qtext;
    $.each(pj.op, function(i, o){
       htm = htm + "<p>" + o.oid + " " + o.option;
    });
});
$("#content").html(htm);
```

Comment: Thanks Jai. Can you help me in displaying the o.option in a <select> drop down list? I am able to parse the entire json now.